# "un-group" Product Features

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

In product-details.tpl the features, when grouped, are printed inside a single

For example:

```
<dl>
   <dt>FEATURE</dt>
   <dd>Value1 Value2 Value3</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to print the following:
Code:

```
<dl>
   <dt>FEATURE</dt>
   <dd>
       <span title="value1">Value1</span>
       <span title="value2">Value2</span>
       <span title="value2">Value3</span>
   </dd>
</dl>
```

This is the original code

```
  {block name='product_features'}
    {if $product.grouped_features}
      <section>
        <h3>{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</h3>
        <dl>
          {foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
            <dt>{$feature.name}</dt>
            <dd>{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}</dd>
          {/foreach}
        </dl>
      </section>
    {/if}
  {/block}
```

I tried

```
{if $product.grouped_features}
      <section>
        <h3>{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</h3>
        <dl>
          {foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
            <dt>{$feature.name}</dt>
            <dd>{foreach $feature.value}<span title="{$feature.value|replace:' ':'_'}">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}</span>{/foreach}</dd>
          {/foreach}
        </dl>
      </section>
{/if}
```

But of course doesn't work..

Most grateful for any help possible.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
{block name='product_features'}
    {if $product.grouped_features}
        <section>
            <h3>{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</h3>
            <dl>
                {foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
                    <dt>{$feature.name}</dt>
                    {assign var=detail_feature value="<br />"|explode:$feature.value} 
                    <dd>
                        {foreach from=$detail_feature item=det_feature}
                            <span title="{$det_feature|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}">{$det_feature|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}</span>
                        {/foreach}
                    </dd>
                {/foreach}
            </dl>
        </section>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Almost, but when the value has more than 1 word it separates them too.. For example is the value is: Value One it prints <span title="Value">Value</span> <span title="One">One</span>

Comment: OK then what is your separator?

Comment: The values are being separated by a <br/>

Comment: It now prints <span title="Value 1<br /> Value 2"> Value 1 <br> Value 2 </span>